# Using other than first row for headers in SQL

Tags: sql, vba, excel

Is is possible to use other than first row for specifying headers in sql query in VBA

in my case the headers are in 4th row(usually they are in 1st row). Is there a way from which vba can detect it.

```
"SELECT [Sheet1$].ID  FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [Sheet1$].Number IS NULL"
```

So in simple terms it expects the ID and Number headers to be in row 1 but I have it in row 4, how can I do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no data in the first three rows, I would have expected your original syntax to work. Perhaps you have data in those rows and just don't want to include it.

In that case you can specify a fixed range, like:

`SELECT [Sheet1$A4:J212].ID  FROM [Sheet1$A4:J212] WHERE [Sheet1$A4:J212].Number IS NULL`

You can also specify a named range, which could be helpful if your list is dynamic:

`SELECT myRange.ID  FROM myRange WHERE myRange.Number IS NULL`

To read more about these options see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257819

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I really appreciate that. I have a simple question regarding this. What is myrange in the example? Is it a simple range like Set myrange=Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5") ?

Comment: No, it's a named range that you create in the workbook, not in VBA. You can do it using Excel's Name Manager (ctrl-F3).